# How do I stop programs and services before the Windows Uninstaller runs

Tags: windows-installer

I'd like to close down my application programs and services before the Windows dialog prompts for 'in use applications to be closed'. The reason for this is that not all users will be aware of the services and apps that are running. I have tried custom actions, Uninstall() OnBeforeUninstall() etc, but these fire AFTER the windows dialog is displayed. Does anyone know of how to do this? (By the way, the uninstaller works ok... its just not too friendly.) The dialog I'm referring to is shown below...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to schedule your stop custom actions before [InstallValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369546%28VS.85%29.aspx) action in [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369500%28VS.85%29.aspx) table. Also, they should require Administrator privileges because it's pretty hard to give the privileges to them at that stage.